# jQuery - How do I make a function loop with a start/end button?

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I'm looking for a way to loop a function over and over until it is stopped by a button and then afterwards it can be resumed. I've google and found some results but they're only limited to loop a specific function..

So is there any way that you can help me?

EDIT:

It should be able to loop through a list of items

```
<ul>
    <li>
<ul>
```

and the transition is supposed to be with fadeOut and then fadeIn the next li.

Comment: Try using setInterval and clearInterval. Post your code example

Comment: Is this some sort of joke? You're editing in further requests!? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @JezenThomas No, my goal is to get an idea of how it works, im sorry if it looks like im trying to  get you to write me a code, that is not the purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

Jquery

```
$("#pause").click(function (){
if (pause){
    timer = setInterval(function(){$("#content").append("Hello world</br>")},1000);
    pause = false;
}
});
$("#resume").click(function(){
if (!pause){
    pause = true;
    clearInterval(timer);
}
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/maT9N/)

Comment: Thanks, i think i got the idea now! I was struggling with getting another script to work and you just made it alot simpler to understand!

Comment: Why -1 any one say reason

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick I think,

```
var yourFun = new function(){
   this.check = false;

   this.run(){
     if( !this.check ) {
       //do all your stuff here.
     }
  }
};

$("#button1").click(function(){ yourFun.run(); });

$("#button2").click(function(){ yourFun.check = true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
var runLoop;

$('#start').click(function() {
    runLoop = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('running');
    }, 100); // time in milliseconds between each loop
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
   clearInterval(runLoop);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9H2PB/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery each function to start and stop loop http://api.jquery.com/each/

The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.